# G abelian Lie group, $(\pi, V)$ a finite-dim unitary rep. $\exists $ mutually orthog. 1-dim invariant linear subspaces s.t $V= \bigoplus_i V_i$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, topological-groups

Let G a commutative Lie group and $(\pi, V)$ a finite-dim unitary representation of G.

I proved that
$\pi \text{ is irreducible iff dim } V = 1\tag 1$

Using this I  want to show that

**There exist mutually orthogonal onedimensional invariant linear subspaces $V_1,..., V_n$ of $V $ such that $V = V_1 \oplus · · · \oplus V_n$.**

My attempt:

I know that every finite-dimensional unitary representation can be decomposed in direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations $V_i\subseteq V: V=\bigoplus_{i} V_i$. How to show that they are mutually orthogonal? Isn't it possible to have a decomposition where they aren't? I am supposed to use (1) here, so the $V_i$'s are one dimensional but I am not sure how is that useful

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{\pi(g):g\in G\}\subset GL(V)$. These are unitary operatots that also commute ($\pi(g_1)\pi(g_2)=\pi(g_1g_2)=\pi(g_2g_1)=\pi(g_2)\pi(g_1))$.

Moreover, as they are unitary, they are also unitarily diagnolizable. It is known that if two unitarily diagnolizable operators commute, then they are mutually unitarily diagnolizable, and by induction this is true for every finite set of unitary operatots that pairwise commute.

Now let $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a unitarily diagnolizing basis for all those operators. Then $V=\bigoplus span\{v_i\}$ is your desired decomposition.

Comment: Why does $\pi(g_1g_2)=\pi(g_2g_1)$? My definition of representation is that  it is an action s.t $\pi(g)$ is linear for every g. And my definition of action is that it is a map $G\times V\to V$ such that there is associativity and the identity element rule. But it does not say that it is an homomorphism of groups anywhere.

Comment: $G$ is abelian so $g_1g_2=g_2g_1$, and a representation of groups is a group homomorphism

Comment: Sorry I  meant why is $\pi(g_1g_2)=\pi(g_1)\pi(g_2)$?

Comment: @some_math_guy Cause a group rep. Is a group homomorphism.

Comment: these are the notes that I am following https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lie2019/lie2010.pdf, Pag 69 def of representation does not say it, but I noticed that is used later in some proofs

Comment: @some_math_guy, see the paragraph under Definition 11.1. Generally with group actions it is useful to be able to fluently change perspective between the "map from $G \times X \to X$" perspective and the "homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Sym}(X)$" perspective. Note that we're saying $g \mapsto \pi(g)$ is a homomorphism where $\pi(g)$ itself is a function and we're talking about the group structure given by function composition.

Comment: GBA, "by induction this is true for every finite set of unitary operatots that pairwise commute" doesn't seem to obviously imply that the family of images of points of $G$ can be simultaneously diagonalised, since $G$ can be infinite.

Comment: Where are we using that the $V_i$'s are 1-dimensional?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen you're correct, for some reason I read that $G$ is finite

Comment: I should say I only meant for that comment to be a small quibble - the answer is still correct I think. It's still true for infinite sets of operators by passing to a finite subset whose linear span contains the whole set. @some_math_guy, it doesn't need to use that - it proves it, in fact. If you want a proof that deduces it from that you could use eg Corollary 20.19.